# Connect Winforms client to mysql on linux server

Tags: mysql, .net, linux, c#-4.0

I have developed a .net 4.0 Windows forms application that is supposed to execute on the client side (all client desktops are windows based with .net 4 framework installed). On the other hand, the server is a Linux server that has a MYSQL database.

I need to know what I need to do in order for my winforms application (on client desktops) to gather/write data from/to the MYSQL database on the server.

Do I need to do some server side programming/scripting in order for the winforms to communicate with the server.
I am new to this, kindly excuse if something sounds 'stupid'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not  `.net` proficient, but most 2 or 3 tiered applications work the same:

In your application, you should have access to a DB driver - like [ODBC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ODBC) - which handles the connection with the DB server, sends it all the queries, and receives the results. All you have to do is specify the connection parameters:

- DB server address
- DB server port
- DB user name
- DB user password

On the server side, you need to configure the server to accept incoming connections from the client:

- setup the DB service: install the DB server and configure it
- configure user and database: create the schema, create the user account, populate the tables
- setup the network: create the firewall rules to let the DB port open to your client connections

And that should be it. Since you will probably have to download the MySQL odbc connector, I suggest that you also consult its [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-odbc.html), which provides tutorials and walk-throughs.

Comment: Afterward, if one of these points causes you problems, just ask a new question and describe the specifics.

Comment: For mysql server or firewall issues, you can check dba.stackexchange.com or serverfault.com

Comment: May I know what exactly you mean by 'set up the DB service'?

Comment: well, I included that point for completeness sake, but from reading your question, it seems that this has already been taken care of.

Comment: slightly clarified the server-side bullets.